# What's the meaning of "allocated to" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading some book about programming language and all of a sudden faced with this part:

> Local variables are declared inside methods, and they only exist
> during the execution of that  method, and once the method returns, **the
> memory allocated to any local variables is released**

my question is about the following part: "the memory allocated to any local variables is released"
1- Is "memory allocated" is originally "memory **is** allocated"?

2- What does exactly the part "**the memory allocated to any local variables is released**" means?
Does it mean that a particular amount of space should be given to local variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The memory allocated** is best understood as **The memory *that has been* allocated.**

> Does it mean that a particular amount of space should be given to local variables?

It means the opposite. Whenever the **method** is **executed**, **memory** is **allocated** for the **variables** that have been declared inside the **method**. A simplified explanation is that space on a microchip has been reserved for the data that each **variable** "contains." No other data will be stored there as long as the **method** exists.

When the **method** returns, the **reserved memory** is **"released."** This means that the application no longer has a record of the **variable**, and it is free to **allocate the memory** to any other data that needs it.